# Options for powering 5 V from 24 V AC relay switch

Tags: power-supply, power

I have four switching relays with internal transformers that control pumps for my heat. From what I can tell they are powered by 120 V and it's stepped-down to 24 V that is sent to the thermostats which then make the connection when heat is needed.

Instead of buying "smart" thermostats I'm going to hook these into my existing system that currently controls my heat pumps. I think the best way to do this is to but a single controller near the boiler that then triggers each zone similar to the way the thermostats do now.

My main question is I need to power the controller so I can either run a separate power source (wall wart) to give it the 5 V or I can hook into the 24 V AC sources and convert that down. If I used relays to control the 24 V AC sources if I used a separate power source it would be isolated so that seems like a bonus but I'd have extra wires running around. If I want to control it from one of the control boxes would it matter which one I used, I'm assuming not since 24 V AC is 24 V AC (for this purpose)?

edit: Adding a sketch as requested. The parts below the line are what exist now and above is what I would like to add.
[image: sketch]

Comment: Yes, 24VAC is 24VAC , but can your existing source provide the current needed?

Comment: It's currently driving the relay and the electronics I'm adding will be insignificant but I'm not sure it can drive all four zones at once. I guess I'll have to figure out what current is needed to switch the relays and verify the transformer can supply this?

Comment: So there are two terminals, +/- that the thermostat ultimately connects. I'm assuming I could power my project with 24vac from a different source and then just connect it to the + terminal to turn on the relay? I'd then only have to run one wire to each control box and everything else would live inside another box powered by it's own 24vac source.

Comment: Can you sketch out a schematic of what you have and of what you are proposing, and add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, it looks like the question is, you have a small electronics box (like a remote control or thermostat) that needs 5VDC and has outputs to control relays. You want to use it to run relays that will switch 24VAC.

It's certainly possible to get 5V from 24VAC, but I think in this case it's going to be easier, cheaper, and more reliable to have a separate 5V wall wart.

Cheaper because: if you need <2A of current, you can get USB power supplies on Amazon for under $10. Power supplies that run off of 24VAC are less common and therefore more expensive.

More reliable because: the switching creates voltage spikes on the 24VAC line, so if your 5V electronics are connected to the 24VAC, it might take a little bit of extra effort to protect them from voltage transients. In industrial systems, it's good practice for different components to be galvanically isolated whenever it's possible to do.

Comment: So if I did that I could just take the 24vac that is currently there and run it up through a relay? Keeps them isolated too and easy to revert if I need to change it back.

Comment: Yeah the contacts of a relay are just a switch, and the coil is isolated from them. So the 5V would power the coil, and that would be a separate circuit from the contacts which switch the 24V.